# Showing large base64 image string in react-native not working?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
<Image style={{width: 150, height: 150, borderRadius: 75}}
       source={{uri: base64image, isStatic: true}} />
```

I have situation where I have to show an image taken by the camera right away after taking the picture. I am taking the base64 image and trying to render it with the `Image` component from `react-native` but it is not showing. I have tried with different base64 string from the internet and it works but they were small in size though.
**I have tried in expo snack as well along with emulator and real device. Same result. Also different version of `react-native`(0.55.3 and 0.55.4)**
So is there an issue or fact that larger size is not supported?

Edit: I have tried checking my base64 image string in online and it showed the photo so it means the string is fine

Comment: Test your implementation with this basic image: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAMAAAC67D+PAAAAA1BMVEXr7MqLt5XVAAAAC0lEQVR4AWOgKwAAAG4AAfBdB/0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=`

Comment: @evolutionxbox this one works! I have tried with different string all works. except the ones are longer (taken from camera usually)

Comment: Hi @ShocKwav3_ did you found any workaround or solution for this issue?

Comment: Hey @Abhishek I ended up using a library called `react-native-image-zoom-viewer` instead.